# How to export access rights of user groups in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Just curious to know to how one can export the access rights of user groups in hybris. Searched hybris wiki but git no help...

Basically i want to retrieve data like(For example):

**UserGroup     Read Create Change**

CronJobGroup    +     -       +

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can generate export scripts in the hMC, you will get:

```
"#% impex.setLocale( new Locale( ""en"" , """" ) );"

"#% impex.setTargetFile( ""UserRight.csv"" , true, 0, 0 );"

"#% impex.exportItems( ""UserRight"" , false );"
```

You can use this in the hac under impex export (or hMC).

Comment: Thanks thijsraets, the script is working fine - what i want.